# Unable to connect to Azure SQL Server. Getting an error "The Network path was not found"

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I created an Azure SQL Server. I have set the firewall, added my IP address to the rules. I tried to log in using SQL Server Managment Studio but got the network error every time. I am using the Server Admin Login and password created while creating the SQL server. Are there any more steps required to log into the SQL Server? 
**Note: I also enabled port 1433 for inbound connections on my PC.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Everyone for your inputs. The only issue was, the firewall was blocking the **port 1433**. After opening it, I could connect to the SQL Server hosted in Azure. The link below mentions the requirement to open the said port. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-develop-direct-route-ports-adonet-v12

Comment: How did you open this port?

Comment: I have found out - I did follow those steps https://www.windowscentral.com/how-open-port-windows-firewall

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message, we should check the server name of the database.
We can select the database here, and SQL Server Managment Studio will type the server name automatically:
[image]

Another way, we can find the information via azure portal, then type the server name manually:
[image]

Comment: The server name and the database name are correct. I think the issue is with the firewall settings on the server side. What settings did you add to it? Just the client side IP? What to do if I have private IP address under a public one?

Comment: @Sameer yes, I just add the client side IP(public IP) to the sql firewall, by default, in azure portal "+Add client IP" will add your client public IP to the firewall settings.

Comment: Now, it is working after opening the port 1433. Anyways, thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Great, It will help others

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using named pipes to connect to SQL database. What happens if you specify TCP/IP protocol in advanced properties tab?
[image]

Comment: I followed your suggestions, but no luck. Now, I am getting "**The wait operation timed out**" error. One more point would like to add,  how should I set up the server side firewall settings? Right now, I have added my public IP there, but I have a private IP address, and I think it's not allowing traffic to that address.